# I feel confusion in linked list.what is the solution?

Tags: c

Specially i feel confusion about passing the head in function.Would any one kindly explain?

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct node    
{    
    int data;

    struct node *next;    
};   

struct node *makeNode(int item)    
{    
    struct node *newNode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    newNode->data = item;

    newNode->next = NULL;

    return newNode;
}    

void traverse(struct node *head)    
{    
    struct node *ptr = head;

    while(ptr != NULL)    
    {    
        printf("%d ",ptr->data);

        ptr = ptr->next;
   }

    printf("\n");
}

void push(struct node **headRef, int data)    
{    
    struct node *newNode = makeNode(data);

    newNode->next = *headRef;

    *headRef = newNode;    
}

void append(struct node **headRef, int data)    
{

    struct node *newNode = makeNode(data);

    struct node *ptr = *headRef, *temp;

    if( ptr == NULL )    
    {    
        *headRef = newNode;

        return;
    }

    while(ptr != NULL)    
    {   

        temp = ptr;

        ptr = ptr->next;    
    }

    temp->next = newNode;    
}


void deleteData(struct node **headRef, int key)    
{    
    struct node *ptr = *headRef, *prevNode;

    //If key is in head node

    if( (ptr->data == key) && (ptr != NULL) )    
    {    
        *headRef = ptr->next;

        free(ptr);

        return;    
    }


    while( (ptr != NULL) && (ptr->data!=key) )    
    {    
        prevNode = ptr;

        ptr = ptr->next;    
    }


    if(ptr == NULL)    
        printf("Underflow or Key not found.\n");    
    else    
    {    
        prevNode->next = ptr->next;    
        free(ptr);    
    }    
}

int main()    
{    
    struct node *head = NULL;

    int data;

    printf("Enter Positive Data:\n");

    scanf("%d",&data);

    while( data>=0 )    
    {    
        append(&head,data);

in this function , pass the address of head.

        scanf("%d",&data);    
    }

    printf("\nTraversing...\n");

    traverse(head);

but in this function why i only pass the head?

    printf("\n\nEnter a data to delete:\n");

    scanf("%d",&data);

    deleteData(&head,data);

    printf("\nTraversing...\n");

    traverse(head);    
}
```

Comment: To change an object passed in a function, you need a pointer to that object. It is not necessary if the object itself is not changed.

Comment: but in the second function why we did not pass the address?

Comment: It is only referenced and it is not modified itself.

Comment: append(&head,data);          traverse(head);

Comment: i see it ,but it does not need to modified>?

Comment: `traverse` does not need to change `head` itself by tracing the pointer.

Comment: oh i get it,thank you very much

Comment: Hint: don't put a blank line between _every_  line of your program.

Comment: i don't understand your syntex, Mr.Michael

Answer (score 1):

**In Function traverse**

```
void traverse(struct node *head) {
    ......
    ......
}
```

Traverse function has a parameter `head` which is of type struct node pointer.
Hence to call `traverse` function you must pass an argument of type struct node pointer.
In main function you defined head as `struct node *head = NULL;`
that's why you are making call to the function like `traverse(head)`.

**In Function append**

```
void append(struct node **headRef, int data)    
{
    ....
    ....

}
```

The argument `headref` is of type 'pointer to pointer'.

> Pointer to Pointer variable stores the address of pointer

Hence, you must pass address of pointer as argument and you make call to append function as `append(&head,data)`

To use pointer as a parameter in append function

Change the return type of you function from void to `struct node*` and return the headRef pointer.

```
struct node* append(struct node *headRef, int data)    
{
    struct node *newNode = makeNode(data);
    struct node *ptr = headRef, *temp;
    if( ptr == NULL )    
    {    
        headRef = newNode;
        return headRef;
    }
    while(ptr != NULL)    
    {   
        temp = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;    
    }
    temp->next = newNode;
    return headref;
}
```

Inside the main function, you should call append function like this.

```
head = append(head,data); //since append function is now returning a pointer
```

**Complete code to append nodes using single pointer**

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct node

{

  int data;

  struct node * next;
};

struct node * makeNode(int item)

{

  struct node * newNode = (struct node * ) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

  newNode -> data = item;

  newNode -> next = NULL;

  return newNode;
}


void traverse(struct node * head)

{

  struct node * ptr = head;

  while (ptr != NULL)

  {

    printf("%d ", ptr -> data);

    ptr = ptr -> next;

  }

  printf("\n");
}

struct node * append(struct node * headRef, int data)

{

  struct node * newNode = makeNode(data);

  struct node * ptr = headRef, * temp;

  if (ptr == NULL)

  {

    headRef = newNode;

    return headRef;

  }

  while (ptr != NULL)

  {

    temp = ptr;

    ptr = ptr -> next;

  }

  temp -> next = newNode;

  return headRef;
}

int main()

{

  struct node * head = NULL;

  int data;

  printf("Enter Positive Data:\n");

  scanf("%d", & data);

  while (data >= 0)

  {

    head = append(head, data);

    scanf("%d", & data);

  }

  printf("\nTraversing...\n");

  traverse(head);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: but why i use pointer to pointer variable in append?if i use only pointer variable ,what's wrong about it ?

Comment: You can also use pointer variable in append function. But you have to return the head in your function.

Comment: Are you changing the return type of your function to `struct node *`?

Comment: void append(struct node *headRef, int data)
{
    struct node *newNode = makeNode(data);
    struct node *ptr = headRef, *temp;
    if( ptr == NULL )
    {
        headRef = newNode;
        return;
    }
    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        temp = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    temp->next = newNode;
}

Comment: i do it,would you please give me the edited code by using only pointer in append(please just edit my code)

Comment: I already edited your code to make it work with pointer. Take a look at the answer. I changed the return type of your append function and added a couple of return statement to you append function.

Comment: no,it give a bug in return newnode,would you please tell why we should change the return type as struct node?

Comment: Did you know about the call by reference and call by value method for callinf a function?

Comment: Do you know about the call by reference and call by value method for calling a function?

Comment: i know about the two topics you told and my eddited code is given in the below.

Comment: Thank you..why we should return headref in every time?

Comment: Since the function has return type that's why we have to return value every time the function is called. Accept the answer if you find it usefull.

Comment: Accept the answer if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Function `append` may alter the value of head (which is a pointer). The signature is therefore `void append(struct node **headRef, int data)`; note the `**`, which denotes a pointer to a pointer. So you have to pass the address of the pointer in order to allow `append` to change the pointer, i.e. call `append(&head,data)`.

Function `traverse`, in contrast, needs not to alter the value of head, so it consumes the pointer directly (and not a pointer to that pointer). The signature is therefore `void traverse(struct node *head)`; note the single `*`. Hence, call it like `traverse(head)`.

Comment: is it mean that,the function traverse only traverse the linked list so that it does not need to pass the address of  pointer head?

Comment: is it mean that,the function traverse only traverse the linked list so that it does not need to pass the address of  pointer head?

Comment: Yes, that is why the signature of traverse is as it is.

Answer (score 0):

## include

struct node

{

```
int data;




struct node *next;
```

};

struct node *makeNode(int item)

{

```
struct node *newNode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

newNode->data = item;




newNode->next = NULL;




return newNode;
```

}

i got bug in the above line

void traverse(struct node *head)

{

```
struct node *ptr = head;





while(ptr != NULL)




{




    printf("%d ",ptr->data);




    ptr = ptr->next;




}




printf("\n");
```

}

i know that there is no need to return the pointer .is it true? if it is true why need to give a return type in the following function?

struct node* append(struct node *headRef, int data)

{

```
struct node *newNode = makeNode(data);




struct node *ptr = headRef, *temp;




if( ptr == NULL )




{




    headRef = newNode;




    return headRef;




}




while(ptr != NULL)




{




    temp = ptr;




    ptr = ptr->next;





}





temp->next = newNode;






return headref;
```

}

int main()

{

```
struct node *head = NULL;





int data;





printf("Enter Positive Data:\n");





scanf("%d",&data);





while( data>=0 )





{





   head=append(head,data);





    scanf("%d",&data);





}





printf("\nTraversing...\n");





traverse(head);
```

}

Comment: You need to return the headRef in append function. For eg. for the first time when the append method is called, initally headRef is NULL you have to return the headRef of the first node.